# Which shader to use in order to render a mesh as is?

Tags: libgdx, rendering, mesh

I am using GL 2.0 (in order to display pictures that are not power of 2), and I am trying to simply render a mesh (that displays some triangles).

When using GL 1.0, I didn't have any problem, but now, I have to pass a ShaderProgram object as a parameter.

How can I make it work like it would in GL 1.0?

Should I make a shader that simply does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a vertex shader to convert world space coordinates into screen space coordinates.  And you need a pixel shader to look up texture coordinates for each rendered pixel of your quad.

Look at the shaders that [Libgdx uses for its `SpriteBatch`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java#L122), they are pretty minimal texture-a-quad shaders.  You can literally use `SpriteBatch.createDefaultShader()` to get them or just use them as inspiration for your own shaders.

Comment: It still doesn't show the triangles as it used to. GL 1.0: http://i.imgur.com/6cdwbiR.png (the triangles are moving towards the edges of the screen) GL 2.0: http://i.imgur.com/SEFcOrA.png (this image is static). I do not change anything else between GL 2.0 and GL 1.0 rather than passing `SpriteBatch.createDefaultShader()` as a parameter to Mesh.render(). If I, on the other hand, create a private variable for the default `ShaderProgram` and I call `begin()` and `end()`, it just shows the pink background as is.

Comment: @hakermania You might have to tweak the shader if your Mesh layout doesn't follow the mesh layout that SpriteBatch uses?

Comment: Any link to follow for more information on what should I tweak?

Comment: Update your question with your `new Mesh` call code (specifically all the `VertexAttribute` parts (compare with https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java#L93).  The shader order must match the mesh order.  You can either fix the shader or your Mesh, but they need to match.

Answer (score 0):

The libgdx wiki page on shaders already contains an example code for a simple shader:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Shaders

I assume it's basically the same as the `createDefaultShader()` as in P.T.'s answer...

Hope it helps...